# Android App with tabs and menu items

Tags: android, menu, tabs, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm trying to implement an application with a specific view. It needs to have a horizontal bar at the top that contains the app icon, and other buttons and spinners. These items must be static and should appear on every page of the app. 
Below that horizontal bar will be a Tabbed component, with the tabs being horizontal at the bottom of the page. I can also implement the desired behavior with the tabs on top of the Tabbed component. Each tab will obviously change the fragment being displayed within the tab's frame.

I am working on an implementation that uses the ActionBar and the menu options. However, I can't get the menu options (my buttons and spinners) to appear above the tabs. And I'm not sure if menu options is the right approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider posting a screenshot/mock of your UI and your issues. It would help others better diagnose and address your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! the answer was right there. I simply had to turn the title bar back on (only with no title) and the menu options would appear right into that title bar.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that this feature is heavily dependent on the version of android and model of device that you have.

Older phones have a menu button which will bring up the same menu, as do some modern phones (like the galaxy SIII), so, be sure to test this everywhere so you know what the end-user will actually experience.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Do you know if we can support both a menu button implementation that brings up a list different from what is included in the menu options of the ActionBar?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you compile your app for Honeycomb and above the various devices will offer your menu in one way or another (generally in the way you expect) without you needing to do anything about it.  If you are compiling for Gingerbread and lower then you need to anticipate all sorts of wacky behavior (and I have no useful guidance on that front... sorry).